# VBA Macro For Naming Ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use the below to run through values in Column A on a Sheet Named "Report" and Create these ranges in a Sheet called "Holidays_Requested" but everytime I it pops up with

> Object Required Runtime error 424.

Can anyone help or know of an alternative way of creating named ranges using VBA.

```
Sub TransposeRange_new_code()
    Dim OutRange As Range
    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    Dim sKey As String
    Dim maxCount As Long
    Dim data, dic, keys, items, dataout()


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    data = Sheets("Report").Range("A2:E" & Report.Cells(Report.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value2


    Set dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set OutRange = Sheets("Holidays_Requested").Range("B2")


    For x = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
        If Trim$(data(x, 1)) <> "_" Then
        sKey = Trim$(data(x, 1)) & Chr(0) & Trim$(data(x, 2))
        If Not dic.exists(sKey) Then dic.Add sKey, CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        dic(sKey).Add x, Array(data(x, 4), data(x, 5))
        If dic(sKey).Count > maxCount Then maxCount = dic(sKey).Count
        End If
    Next


    ReDim dataout(1 To maxCount + 1, 1 To dic.Count * 3)
    keys = dic.keys
    items = dic.items
    For x = LBound(keys) To UBound(keys)
        dataout(1, x * 3 + 1) = Split(keys(x), Chr(0))(0)
        dataout(1, x * 3 + 2) = Split(keys(x), Chr(0))(1)
        For y = 1 To items(x).Count
            dataout(1 + y, x * 3 + 1) = items(x).items()(y - 1)(0)
            dataout(1 + y, x * 3 + 2) = items(x).items()(y - 1)(1)
        Next y
    Next




    OutRange.Resize(UBound(dataout, 1), UBound(dataout, 2)).Value2 = dataout


    For x = 1 To UBound(keys)
        OutRange.Offset(0, (x - 1) * 3).Resize(maxCount, 2).Name = "" & validName(Split(keys(x - 1), Chr(0))(0))
        With OutRange.Offset(0, (x - 1) * 3 + 1)
            .Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=.Cells(1), Address:="mailto://" & .Value2, TextToDisplay:=.Value2
        End With
    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: where are you trying to set a `Named Range` ? what line ? what variable you intended to use for the `Named Range` ?

Comment: I believe it is                                                                  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
data = Sheets("Report").Range("A2:E" & Report.Cells(Report.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value2


Set dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

Comment: Which line specifically? You've given *three* lines, but the error can only raise on one of them. I suspect it's the call to `Report.Rows`, unless `Report` object is globally-scoped and instantiated in another routine. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you're referring to a non-instantiated variable `Report`. Since this variable hasn't been declared with a `Dim` statement, it will be treated as an empty variant, zero-length string, or 0-value numeric, or a `Nothing` object, depending on how/when you call upon it.

And since you're doing `Report.__something__` the compiler assumes it's supposed to be an `Object` (since only `Object` type have properties/methods). Since it doesn't exist and/or hasn't been assigned, you're doing essentially: `Nothing.Cells...`

This will always raise a 424 because in order to invoke *any* `.__something__` call, you need to invoke it against a valid, existing `Object`.

Change:

```
data = Sheets("Report").Range("A2:E" & Report.Cells(Report.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value2
```

To:

```
With Sheets("Report")
    data = .Range("A2:E" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value2
End With
```

As always, using `Option Explicit` in each module will prevent you from executing/running code with undeclared variables. I would recommend adding that statement at the top of each code module, and then rectifying any compile errors (such as `Variable undefined`) which might arise.

Also: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) for more reliable ways of finding the "last" cell in a given range.

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094267/are-there-any-advantages-of-using-option-explicit-off-in-visual-basic-net) is a VB.NET (similar conceptually) explanation of why you should be using `Option Explicit`.